# how to achieve permutation and combination from a single table based on cost using mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, combinations, permutation

I have a table where

- *sr_id* is primary_key with auto increment
- *skuid* is identification number for each product &
- *price* is cost for that product

Table name: *sample_records*

```
sr_id | skuid | price
----------------------
   1  | SKOO1 | 12
   2  | SKOO2 | 7
   3  | SKOO3 | 56
   4  | SKOO4 | 3 
   5  | SKOO5 | 23
   6  | SKOO6 | 50 
   7  | SKOO7 | 34
   8  | SKOO8 | 5 
   9  | SKOO9 | 23
   10 | SKO10 | 56 
   11 | SKO11 | 101
   12 | SKO12 | 4 
   13 | SKO13 | 23
   14 | SKO14 | 56
```

Now I need a combination based on price. Let's say I am giving the cost as 500. Below is the expected result:

```
ROW | skuid             | quantity  | cost |
---------------------------------------------
 1  | SKOO1             |    41     |  492
--------------------------------------------- 
 2  | SKOO1,SKOO2       |    41,1   |  497
--------------------------------------------- 
 3  | SKOO1,SKOO2       |    40,2   |  494
--------------------------------------------- 
 4  | SKOO1,SKOO2,SKOO8 |    40,2 1 |  499
---------------------------------------------
 .
 .
 .
```

The result should get all combinations..
**Note**:-

1. quantity and cost are dynamically added columns.

Please help me to get a feasible solution.

Comment: What have you researched / attempted so far? Where exactly are you stuck? Stackoverflow is not a free write-my-code service, but we'll _help_ you with _your_ attempt to solve the problem. Please demonstrate your efforts so far. Thanks. See [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: This is a classic Knapsack problem, but I can’t give you reference materials in English. Maybe you can search with Knapsack problem as a keyword

Comment: What is quantity?  You don't define it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to get the permutations:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select cast(skuid as char(1000)) skuids, price, skuid as max_skuid
      from sample
      where price < 50
      union all
      select concat_ws(',', cte.skuids, s.skuid), cte.price + s.price, s.skuid
      from cte join
           sample s
           on s.skuid > cte.max_skuid and
              s.price + cte.price < 50
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1a06e183618cd316efd6e1177140bd0) is a db<>fiddle.